# Script to add users will add users but they cannot login

Tags: linux, shell-script, files, scripting, fedora

I have a script that will add users from a file. It will add the users just fine as far as I can tell, but when trying to login the password supplied by the script does not work. I'm not sure if this is normal or not, but the /etc/shadow file also shows the correct passwords in plain text. I thought the shadow file is only supposed to show a hash?

Here is the code I have for the script:

```
#/bin/bash
file="/Scripts/FormattedFile.txt"
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 f4
do
validID=$( echo "$f3" | cut -b 4,5,6,7,8,9 )
comment="${f1} ${f2}"
useradd -m -p "$f3" -u "$validID" -c "$comment" "$f1"
echo "Added user $f1."
done < "$file"
```

The result is a user with the correct username, ID, and home directory, but is unable to login. I know that the script is reading the file correctly and the fields are also correct as pulled from the file. Field 3 is a 6 digit number taken from a longer 9 digit string.

Each record is of the format:

```
firstname:lastname:H00123456:abc1234@domain.com
```

Records are separated by a newline.

Comment: I explored using passwd but it doesn't seem to want to take a stream of input.

Comment: For what it's worth, `chpasswd` will update one or many passwords, reading `username:cleartextpassword` pairs from stdin.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to `useradd --help`:

```
-p, --password PASSWORD       encrypted password of the new account
```

So what you need to do is to pass the *encrypted* password:

```
-p $(openssl passwd "the_password")
```

Comment: Also if your default shell is set to /bin/false or /bin/nologin, they won't be able to log in. You need to add -s /bin/bash.